Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a semi-algebraic set with co-dimension $\geq 2$. Then $A^c$ is path-connected.
I'm looking for a resource that claims and proves the following. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a semi-algebraic set whose dimension is at most $N - 2$. Then the complement $A^c = \mathbb{R}^n - A$ is path-connected. I've seen similar questions posted here, however none have posted a textbook or published paper proving it. I was hoping someone could provide me with a resource showing this.
